# Convert email address from X400 to SMTP

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I'm trying to get the SMTP address from an X400 address in VB.Net.  If I bring up the Outlook properties for a user in our domain, and look at the "Email Addresses", I can see the SMTP address, but I need to get at it through code.  I tried inspecting the Address Book in OutlookSpy to see if I could come up with a property in the outlook object model that exposes it, but I'm coming up dry.

For work reasons, I'm also not able to use Outlook Redemption, which seems like it might have a solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How come you cannot use outlook redemption? I have just solved this problem using redemption.

Comment: We can, but as it's a commercial product, we prefer not to spend $200 dollars.  In any case, we were able to get around this by querying Active Directory in the case where the email originated internally.